# Raspbmc Dropbear not using provided cmdline arguments

Tags: ssh, xinetd, dropbear

I have a raspbmc running on my rPi. Already configured to use ssh keys but I want to disable the password login option entirely.

I have added the -s option in the /etc/default/dropbear:

```
# any additional arguments for Dropbear
DROPBEAR_EXTRA_ARGS= -s
```

I also added it to /etc/init.d/dropbear

However then I read xinetd is used to manage SSH and launch Dropbear. So I went over to /etc/xinetd.d/ssh and changed the following, adding -s:

```
server_args = -i -s
```

Now when I stop the dropbear service and restart the xinetd service I still only see dropbear being launched with only -i and password logins still work.

Not sure where else I'd have to change the command line arguments, any hints would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## From the Dropbear man page

- -w Disallow root logins.
- -s Disable password logins.
- -g Disable password logins for root.

nano /etc/default/dropbear

## Find the DROPBEAR_EXTRA_ARGS parameter and change it as shown below.

DROPBEAR_EXTRA_ARGS=”-s -g”

## Finally, restart dropbear.

/etc/init.d/dropbear restart